# Many-To-Many Relationship in Spring Boot not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm mapping some SQL Server tables to Java entity classes using Spring Boot. In SQL, I've got these 3 tables: EXHIBITIONS (with PK exhibition_id), TARGET_AUDIENCES (with PK target_audience_id), and AUDIENCES_BY_EXHIBITIONS (with just two columns: exhibition_id target_audience_id).
This is `Exhibition`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXHIBITIONS")
public class Exhibition {
@Id
@Column(name = "exhibition_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int exhibitionId;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "AUDIENCES_BY_EXHIBITIONS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "exhibition_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "target_audience_id"))
private List<TargetAudience> targetAudience;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Exhibition{" +
            "targetAudience=" + targetAudience +
            '}';
}
```

And this is the `TargetAudience` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TARGET_AUDIENCES")
public class TargetAudience {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "target_audience_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int targetAudienceId;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the `toString()` method is throwing an error. At first, I thought it was because I didn't add this attribute on `TargetAudience`:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "targetAudience")
List<Exhibition> exhibition;
```

I've managed to map One-To-One associations, but I can't get this to work. The problem comes when I try to show them in a JavaFX combo box. I thought it was because of JavaFX, but I've tried making a simple CLI app like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Playground implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ExhibitionRepo exhibitionRepo;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Playground.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        List<Exhibition> exhibitions = exhibitionRepo.findAll();

        for (Exhibition e:
                exhibitions) {
            System.out.println(e + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error thrown:

```
2021-06-13 08:08:59.701  INFO 8944 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-06-13 08:08:59.717 ERROR 8944 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:344) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at com.app.Playground.main(Playground.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.app.Exhibition.targetAudiences, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:606) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:621) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar:5.4.31.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
    at com.Exhibition.toString(Exhibition.java:141) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.simpleConcat(StringConcatHelper.java:407) ~[na:na]
    at com.app.Playground.run(Playground.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2021-06-13 08:08:59.720  INFO 8944 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-13 08:08:59.722  INFO 8944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-06-13 08:08:59.725  INFO 8944 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: what is the error that `toString` is throwing

Comment: Hi can u please specify  what error u are getting and on what operation u are getting.
I took the above entity classes and ran. It created 3 tables without any errors.

Comment: The above code seems correct. As @aRvi said mentioning the error thrown will be helpful.

Comment: It's not in the toString() exactly, it's in the JavaFX combo box that lists all the Exhibitions. I'll update the post.

Comment: same procedure as always: [mcve] please ... ;) separate out the back-end from the fx part, in particular, make sure that you use access the items in the comboBox correctly (no need for the db part, just hard-code some data)

Comment: I've just tried it in a simple command-line app, still not working. It wasn't related to JavaFX.

Comment: _It wasn't related to JavaFX_ good could separate it ... removed the fx tag again :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` in the Exhibition class fixed the issue:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXHIBITIONS")
public class Exhibition {
@Id
@Column(name = "exhibition_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int exhibitionId;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "AUDIENCES_BY_EXHIBITIONS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "exhibition_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "target_audience_id"))
private List<TargetAudience> targetAudience;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Exhibition{" +
            "targetAudience=" + targetAudience +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please help me with my many to many problem, thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257277/spring-updating-many-to-manay-reletionship/77259130?noredirect=1#comment136208510_77259130